# PHP + FPDF + Script MEM_IMAGE - Align and Valign a imagen into a Cell

Tags: php, image, cell, fpdf

I would like to align/valign a image in a cell.
Until now i have this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWQKP.jpg

*`$pdf->Cell(50,50,$pdf->MemImage($image,10,10,30),1,0,"R");`*

It is not align into right.
How could i do it?

Thanks